# AddDays(1) in List<DateTime> list item when midnight reach

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem, have a list of datetime collection, combined with date selected from drop down but  time slot is added from 7am to 4am (21 hours). I want to fix the date in this collection in a way that if reach to hour 00 or 24 (12AM midnight), the the date should change.

(Note: The date is same in all items as date and time was added separately)

This is the function I am trying but its not perfect.

```
        private void CheckFixDateinList(List<TimeSlot> lstTimeSlots)
    {
        Boolean bHourChanged = false;
        int Fromlasthour = 0;
        int Tolasthour = 0;

        foreach(TimeSlot UEP in lstTimeSlots)
        {
            if (Fromlasthour < UEP.TimeSlotFrom.Hour)
                bHourChanged = true;

            if (bHourChanged)
                UEP.TimeSlotFrom = UEP.TimeSlotFrom.AddDays(1);

            Fromlasthour = UEP.TimeSlotFrom.Hour;



            if (UEP.TimeSlotFrom.Hour > Tolasthour)
                bHourChanged = true;

            if (bHourChanged)
                UEP.TimeSlotFrom = UEP.TimeSlotFrom.AddDays(1);

            if (bHourChanged )
                if (UEP.TimeSlotTo.Hour < UEP.TimeSlotFrom.Hour)
                    UEP.TimeSlotTo = UEP.TimeSlotTo.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
```

The datastructure is here

```
public class TimeSlot
{
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }
    public int NumOfEmpl { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
    public string PDRowID { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeSlotFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeSlotTo { get; set; }

    public TimeSlot()
    {
        this.CreateDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        this.NumOfEmpl = 0;
        this.TimeSlot = "";
        this.Deleted = 0;
        this.PDRowID = "";
        this.TimeSlotFrom = DateTime.Now.Date;
        this.TimeSlotTo = DateTime.Now.Date;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is lstTimeSlots sorted by TimeSlotFrom?  Also, could you give us a sample of what the dates are in the List?

Comment: yes its sorted but it could have different timeslots how user enters. Sorry cannot format this reply here.

Like there could be gaps in time slots from minutes to hours. 
E-g. slot data could be    
TimeSlotFrom                 TimeSlotTo
2014-10-02 07:00:00.000 2014-10-02 08:00:00.000
2014-10-02 08:00:00.000 2014-10-02 09:00:00.000
2014-10-02 22:30:00.000 2014-10-02 23:00:00.000
2014-10-02 02:10:00.000 2014-10-02 03:10:00.000

Comment: What is TimeSlot? Is it a part of .Net or something you've defined?

Comment: Its just a 'DateTime' field in my class structure.

Comment: But, but ... it must be a class or struct if you can define a List<> of them? It makes it difficult to understand your question when you don't provide the necessary definitions.

Comment: OK I have added the data structure here too.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got my result for the time being but not satisfied and feel it could be better.

```
    private void CheckFixDateinList(List<TimeSlot> lstTimeSlots)
    {
        Boolean bHourChanged = false;
        int Fromlasthour = 0;
        int Tolasthour = 0;

        foreach(TimeSlot UEP in lstTimeSlots)
        {
            if (UEP.TimeSlotFrom.Hour < Fromlasthour)
                bHourChanged = true;

            if (bHourChanged)
                UEP.TimeSlotFrom = UEP.TimeSlotFrom.AddDays(1);

            Fromlasthour = UEP.TimeSlotFrom.Hour;

            if (bHourChanged )
              UEP.TimeSlotTo = UEP.TimeSlotTo.AddDays(1);

            if (UEP.TimeSlotTo < UEP.TimeSlotFrom)
            {
                bHourChanged = true;
                UEP.TimeSlotTo = UEP.TimeSlotTo.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do a check if (hours < 5 || hours == 12(am) ) then add 1 day?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure I understand what you are doing, but here's a suggestion.

```
  public class TimeSlot
  {
     // some fields temporarily removed 
     public DateTime TimeSlotFrom { get; set; }
     public DateTime TimeSlotTo { get; set; }

     public TimeSlot()
     {
        // some fields temporarily removed 
        this.TimeSlotFrom = DateTime.Now.Date;
        this.TimeSlotTo = DateTime.Now.Date;
     }


     /// <summary>
     /// Method to move the end date forward one day if the start and end dates are the same and 
     /// the end time is less than the start time, for example start hour = 7 and end hour = 4.
     /// </summary>
     public void AdjustEndDateIfNecessary()
     {
        if (TimeSlotFrom.Date == TimeSlotTo.Date &&
            TimeSlotFrom.Hour > TimeSlotTo.Hour)
        {
           TimeSlotTo = TimeSlotTo.AddDays(1);
        }
     }


     /// <summary>
     /// Method to move the whole time slot (both start and end time) by incrementing by one day.
     /// </summary>
     public void IncrementTimeSlotByOneDay()
     {
        TimeSlotFrom = TimeSlotFrom.AddDays(1);
        TimeSlotTo = TimeSlotTo.AddDays(1);
     }
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Method to go through a List{} of TimeSlot objects and do two things:
  /// - "normalize" them by fixing the end date if it is wrong
  /// - push time slots into the future if they overlap with the previous time slot. (This has a 
  /// cascading effect, so the last time slot may end up several days in the future.)
  /// </summary>
  private void CheckFixDateInList(List<TimeSlot> timeSlots)
  {
     DateTime highestEndTimeSoFar = DateTime.MinValue;

     foreach (TimeSlot timeSlot in timeSlots)
     {
        timeSlot.AdjustEndDateIfNecessary();

        while (timeSlot.TimeSlotFrom < highestEndTimeSoFar)
        {
           timeSlot.IncrementTimeSlotByOneDay();
        }

        highestEndTimeSoFar = timeSlot.TimeSlotTo;
     }
  }
```

Note that I've tried to make things a bit more object-oriented by putting two parts of the code inside the TimeSlot class.

I must admit I haven't tested this, partly because I'm not even sure I've understood what you are doing.